how to set static form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded parameters in body of a request in wso2 api manager
I want to configure static form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded parameters in the body of a request using wso2 api manager .
I used the following configs but they didn't work .
thank you in advance for your help !
I used the following configs but they didn't work .
first :
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="main">    
    <payloadFactory description="transform" media-type="xml">
      <format>
            client_id=$1&
            client_secret=$2&
            grant_type=$3&
            username=$4&
            password=$5                     
        </format>
      <args>                  
         <arg evaluator="xml" value="client_id"/>
         <arg evaluator="xml" value="client_secret"/>         
         <arg evaluator="xml" value="grant_type"/>
         <arg evaluator="xml" value="username"/>
         <arg evaluator="xml" value="password"/>
      </args>       
    </payloadFactory>           
</sequence>

and second :
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="main">
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
          <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">username=username&amp;password=password&amp;grant_type=grant_type</text>
      </format>
      <args/>
    </payloadFactory> 
</sequence>

